# Correcting Django User Model Foreign Key issue

Tags: python, django

I am using the built-in django user model. I keep getting the error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

I did not use the user model in any other models and vice-versa.

models.py looks like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models import BooleanField
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models import DateTimeField

class Course(models.Model): 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    desc = CharField(max_length=150)
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    storyboard_file_path = TextField()
    storyboard_completed = BooleanField(default=False)
    filming_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    audio_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    production_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    aggregation_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    video_file_path = TextField()
    final_review_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projects", null=True, blank=True)

class Status(models.Model):
    status_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    desc = CharField(max_length=150)
    name = CharField(max_length=50)

class Event(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    status_id = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py looks like this

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Event
from .models import Project
from .models import Course
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 
        "password",
        "last_login",
        "is_superuser",
        "username",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "is_staff",
        "is_active",
        "date_joined",
        "groups",
        "user_permissions")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def get_jwt_token(user):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
        return jwt_encode_handler(payload)

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'desc', 'name', 'storyboard_file_path', 
        'storyboard_completed', 'filming_complete', 'audio_complete',  
        'production_complete', 'aggregation_complete', 'video_file_path',
        'final_review_complete', 'course')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class CouserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'projects')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I am trying to load in the fixture

```
{
    "model": "auth.user",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$120000$V2isoXl1Q88l$sVuB+25I6UNNLY76Ti0EixAu/Ucimqi7rFpbadDzqzc=",
        "last_login": null,
        "is_superuser": true,
        "username": "admin@admin.com",
        "first_name": "Admin",
        "last_name": "User",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2019-04-16T00:16:13.252Z",
        "groups": [1],
        "user_permissions": []
    }
},
{
    "model": "auth.user",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$120000$6YHv5JMayFnN$+Y2TqedyjZq02kEw/0ZaXtyigzaH2+BRUIqqkSeAG90=",
        "last_login": null,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "content@content.com",
        "first_name": "Content",
        "last_name": "Manager",
        "email": "content@content.com",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2019-04-16T00:19:01.130Z",
        "groups": [2],
        "user_permissions": []
    }
}
]
```

I do not understand where this foreign key error is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you created the groups 1 & 2 for the sample users / are you sure they exist? (They are the only foreignKey to User).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the groups.  Do those groups exist (before the users).  If not you would get this error.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!